# What does X f() mean?

Tags: c++

I see this code and I can't understand what it mean.
I know how we use default constructor but this is not default constructor. What is this?

```
class X
{
        ...
};

int main()
{
     X f();
}
```

Comment: It's a function declaration - a nullary function that returns an X.

Comment: In main?? Like lambda?

Comment: @Aryan: Not at all like a lambda. It's like a forward declaration, more like.

Answer (score 8):

It declares a function `f` which takes no parameters and returns a type `X`.
This is also known as **[Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)** in C++. It is a byproduct of the way the C++ standard defines the interpretation rules for declarations.

Comment: +1. However, this is usually just called a "Vexing parse." Most of the time, I've seen "Most vexing parse" refer to `X f(X())`.

Comment: @Angew: Let me be a little more specific, `X f(X())` has always been classically designated as the *Most Vexing Parse*, some consider `X f()` to be as vexing as the former and consider it similar and name it likewise, Some consider `X f()` to be more predictable as a function declaration than the original vexing parse and hence do not consider it as the *Most vexing parse* at all. It is more of an perception based nomenclature than standerdese terminology and so there is no uniformity per se. Glad you brought that up.Thank you.

Comment: @Angew - it's funny, after almost 20 years of C++ development, I just ran afoul of the _most_ vexing parse yesterday.  I guess until now I've never tried that construct and I expected it to work, knowing all about the vexing parse.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you declare a function:

```
int Random();
```

And use it:

```
int main()
{
   int n;
   n = Random();
}
```

But implement the Random function after `main`. Or assume that `Random` function is defined in some header. You need to instruct the compiler that `Random` is a function implemented in some other source file, or in some library.

Therefore, an expression like:

```
T foo();
```

Would always mean a instruction to compiler that there is a function named `foo` which returns `T`. It cannot be an object of type `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Its function declaration of name `f`

```
  X          f();
  ^          ^ function   
  return type
```

function `f()` takes no arguments and  returns a `X` class object.

for example its definition can be like:

```
class X{
   int i;
   // other definition
}

X f(){ 
    X x;
    // some more code
    return x; 
}
```

In main you can use like:

```
int main(){

 X a = f();
 int i = f().i;
}
```

Comment: Why we need something like this?

Comment: @Aryan its just simmilar like `int f(){ i = 10; return i;}` need need to return X class object in calling function. @Ajay provided very good example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function which doesn't take any argument and returns an object of class X