# What is the difference between class a() and class a = class() in C++?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

Coming from the Java and C# world, I always like to use

```
someclass a = someclass();
```

instead of

```
someclass a();
```

to initalize a class variable in C++. However, my compiler sometimes complain

```
Error C2280: Attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Is there any difference between them? Which one is better?

Comment: Big difference. You can start with [What does X f(); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653345/what-does-x-f-mean)

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I'd imagine a lack of [mcve] and lack of research will usually garner downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any difference between them?

A big one: [`someclass a();` is declaring a function!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653345/what-does-x-f-mean)

And `someclass a = someclass();`, before [C++17's copy ellision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), requires the class to be movable, which is probably not the case here as you get the error `Attempting to reference a deleted function`.

> Which one is better?

None. Use instead:

```
someclass a;
```

or

```
someclass a{}; // C++11
```

Both will call [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

Comment: How about classes with constructors that require parameters? Are someclass a(param) and someclass a = someclass(param) same besides the cons you have mentioned?

Comment: @AmazingJustus The `someclass a()` special case considered as function declaration applies mostly when there isn't any parameter. But you can find some cases with parameters such as `someclass a(someother())` which will also result in function declaration.

Comment: These will ba corrected by using curly braces or adding extra parenthesis: `someclass a( (someother()) )`.

Comment: As of `someclass a(param)` againts `someclass a = someclass(param)`, the first will be prefered.

Answer (score -2):

Dear Friend in  C++ user creates the object as follows

[image: steps]

classname objectname;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class demo
{
   public:
      void print()
         {
           cout<<"Demo class";
         }
 };
int main()
   {

      demo d;
      d.print();
      return 0;
   }
```

OUTPUT
Demo class

using pointer object

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class demo
{
   public:
      void print()
         {
           cout<<"Demo class using pointer object";
         }
 };

int main()
   {

      demo *d = new demo();
      d->print();
      return 0;
   }
```

OUTPUT
Demo class using pointer object

In java, garbage collection is done automatically. I hope that you understand concept.

Comment: Recommendation: To beat home your closing statement you should add `delete d;` to the final `main`. A correction: `void main()` is invalid in C++. The C++ standard requires that `main` return `int`. A minor niggle: You can go an entire programming career and never see anything but stack and heap, but C++ does not require stacks and heaps. Stack and heap are just the most common (by far) implementations of Automatic and Dynamic storage.

Comment: void main() will work in turboc.it is not invalid statement. In gcc compiler it is mandatory to specify as int. in my third point i specified that delete operator has to be used to deallocates the memory. i attached the turbo c complier screen shot in my answer

Comment: @K.Vani Saying that some compiler compiles something does not mean it is valid C++ code. Compilers have errors, and older compilers (like turboc) tend to have loads of them.

Comment: @K.Vani TurboC++ came and went before C++ was standardized in 1998. It is a different language. Knowing one, you can muddle your way through the other just like you can with C and C++, but there are numerous differences that will trip you up. This is one of them.